# Where does SharePoint store the real files?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I add a new document in SharePoint (like a Microsoft Word document) where exactly is the file (binary data) stored?

In an MSSQL engine? (BLOB?)
On a hard drive as a native file?

Somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

By default, it is stored in the SQL Server Content Database associated with the site collection.  However, Sharepoint 2010 does support storing list data as BLOBs in external storage.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748607.aspx for more information.